# Как двигать div с содержимым?

Tags: html, css

Когда я пробую подвигать div c номером телефона и иконкой, с помощью margin-bottom, то у меня не получается. (там где есть border это то что у меня, а вторая картинка, как должно быть)
[image: то что у меня]
[image: нужный результат]

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

div {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.main {
    background: gray;
    width: 1880px;
    height: 94px;
}

.itvdn_logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.icons {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fp {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="3.css">
    <title>Задание 3.</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="itvdn_logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="itvdn logo">
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <img src="images/phone icon.png" alt="phone icon">
            <p class="fp">800 337 146</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: лучше было не удалять [предыдущий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1421746/178576) вопрос, а дополнить его.

Comment: извините, я там запутался, и решил задать его заново.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать с помощью transform: translateX(-кол-во пикселей-) и TranslateY

Comment: нет( должно быть что-то проще, я выучил только display, margin, padding, и это надо сделать используя только эти свойства, и я уже сколько времени не могу понять, почему margin-bottom проваливается и как это исправить(((

Comment: @Denys вот и используйте display, если выучили, только со значением flex

Comment: А flex это следующая тема, сначала нужно выполнить с такими значениями: inline, block либо inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки нельзя было решить это тем набором что был у меня (padding, margin, display: block/inline/inline-block) и мне подсказали добавить position: absolute и div сдвинулся с мёртвой точки, если кто знает как можно решить ответ способом который мне был нужен, буду благодарен

Comment: я ответил, помотри

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    height: 94px;
    line-height: 94px;
}

.itvdn_logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin: auto 0;
}

.icons {
    margin-left: 900px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fp {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```